# View the change history of a file compared to a remote branch

Tags: git, git-log

I am looking for a method to see the changes I made to a file.

What I would like to find is the things I have changed and commited locally. Furthermore I would also like to see the unpulled remote changes.

I would like to know what's going to happen to a file before I do a pull and I would like to know what I'm gonna push before I do a push.

Comment: git pull is shortcut for git fetch and git merge. I would *always* advise not to use git pull unless you know exactly what you are doing. (This is obviously not the case if you are pulling changes you have not seen before). So first use git fetch, then compare as others have already answered. After that you can decide what to do. I you think merging is what you want you can call git merge or git pull. Now in git pull the fetch part will be empty (well, again as I said, you know what you are doing, so you know that nobody has pushed anything in the meantime...) and then git will do the merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `git fetch`,
then `git diff --stat --color master..origin/master`

Remove the `--stat` if you want to see the full diff.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to find is the things I have changed and commited locally.

```
git log origin/branch..HEAD
```

> Furthermore I would also like to see the unpulled remote changes.

```
git fetch origin
git log HEAD..FETCH_HEAD
```

> I would like to know what I'm gonna push before I do a push.

```
git add file1
git diff --cached file1
```